# Blueimp jQuery File Upload - Can't change the input name

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

I try to use the BlueImp jQuery File Uploader (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin). It works well, but only with the orinial name attribute of the input field, "files[]".
When I use an other name, the JSON response is empty :

{"files":[]}

This is my code :

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>Photos</label>
    </td><td id="photos_container">
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
        </div>
        <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
            <span>Select files...</span>
            <input id="photos" type="file" name="photos[]" multiple>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $(function () {
            $('#photos_container').fileupload({
                url: 'tmp/',
                dataType: 'json',
                fileInput: $('#photos'),
                paramName: 'photos[]',
                progressall: function (e, data) {
                    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                    $('#photos_container .progress .bar').css(
                        'width',
                        progress + '%'
                    );
                },
                done: function (e, data) {
                    $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                        $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#photos_container');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I repeat, but the code works great with the default name of input button "files[]", so the problem isn't a path problem.

EDIT: And I try with and without the fileInput and the paramName options, but I didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The `name` attribute is used to reference elements in a JavaScript, or to reference form data after a form is submitted.

Your file data will be there in `photos` property.